# Mean and variance: Gaussian is the most conservative assumption

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation, standard-deviation

"given only the mean and variance of a distribution, the most conservative assumption that can be made about the distribution is that it is a Gaussian having the given mean and variance"

I've read this in the context of Kalman filters in this [paper](http://www.smpp.northwestern.edu/savedLiterature/JulierUhlmannUnscented.pdf) (at bottom of page 1) and I wonder what this means. What is the most conservative assumption, in what sense?

Comment: Where did you read this? Without further context, this just seems bogus...

Comment: thank you for your remark. I did not know that the context is important, so now I've linked the paper.

Comment: @fgp how is this bogus? the gaussian is very well known to be a maximum entropy distribution under those constraints. the above statement is true in many contexts.

Comment: @KaiSikorski That still presupposes *some* context, though - e.g. that higher entropy is somehow worse. Still a very good answer, though.

Comment: @fgp I suppose you're right; context is never bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gaussian is the "maximum entropy" probability distribution under those constraints.

It means you are imposing the least other information on the distribution.

Loosely speaking another way to think of it, is that if you put all the distributions in a big bag and then you picked one at a time until you got one that was within some predefined threshold of the mean and variance you want; you'd be much much much more likely to end up with something that looks pretty close to a normal than with anything else.